# Getting 400 for the MSOneDrive Update rest api

Tags: javascript, onedrive

I was trying to send request to update the file. Below is the request I am sending

But I am getting 400 bad request. Could anyone please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: `
PATCH -     https://api.onedrive.com:443/v1.0/drive/items/E673B0AD48D29F69!7515

Query Params : {
 "name": "update_file-name.docx",
 }
`

Comment: PATCH - https://api.onedrive.com:443/v1.0/drive/items/E673B0AD48D29F69!7515

Comment: Could any one please help me here,I went throught this link https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm